# MapReduce with "customized" key

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, equals, gridgain

I have the following problem: I have a lot of data in form of key-value pairs. The key is some id and the value - some piece of text. And my aim is to group that objects in clusters where the text pieces are "similar" in some way. So it would look like a task for the MapReduce, if to take my text piece as a key, and id as a value. But such keys is not traditional way of MapReduce usage, and as I am not really aware of internal implemetation of MapReduces frameworks, I am not sure that this way works. So my idea in detail is:
1. take some MapReduce in Java (Hadoop, GridGain)
2. create special class for my text pieces (say TextKey)
3. Override equals() of the class, packing the text comparison logic here(say levenstein distance comparison, or whatever)
4. Override compareTo() for allowing the MapReduce to sort by key (say lexicographical order)
5. Probably override hashCode()
6. Map my data to key-value pairs: keys -> text pieces, packed in TextKey class, values -> ids
7. Simply reduce by collecting ids of every "equal" (actually similar) key

Can MapReduce work on that way?

Answer (score 3):

In GridGain this can be easily solved by storing your text keys in partitioned data grid. GridGain Data Grid will automatically partition your data set across the cluster based on keys, so as long as you have your similar text pieces properly implement standard java hashCode() and equals(), you should be fine.

You can also send affinity-based MapReduce tasks in GridGain to make sure that your jobs end up on the same node as the data to avoid redundant data movements should you require to run some computations on your data going forward. This can be achieved by executing GridProjection.affinityRun(...) methods.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right after the map phase, its output is partitioned using a Partitioner (HashPartitioner by default but you can provide your own Parititioner). Your TextKey should implement a LSH hashCode so that similar Text values are likely to go to the same partition.
2. If the keys are Strings/Text objects the default sorter will work but I think this is not going to affect your result given the scenario you described.
3. The problem is at the Grouper which passes each group within a partition to a single reduce call. By default this grouper iterates through the partition which is sorted by this moment and it forms groups out of equal values. In your case you should make sure the grouping is done not by equality but by similarity. So, your TextKey should also implement the `compareTo()` method and take care to return 0 if the LSH hashCodes are the same.

In conclusion you can go with the default data path (i.e. default Partitioner, Sorter, Grouper) but your TextKey (which should implement WritableComparable) should do the magic in the `hashCode()` and `compareTo()` methods